# Dataframe exportation to excel (shift of rows)

Tags: python, pandas

When I export my dataframe to excel format, I have a missmatch with the columns header as follow. DATES and test are not on the same row.

Has someone any idea on how to correct that ?

```
            test
DATES   
2014-01-01  0.564772067
2014-01-02  0.070382608
2014-01-03  1.640314224
2014-01-04  -0.00894445
2014-01-05  -0.224146506
```

and my code:

```
new_index = pd.date_range(start=pd.datetime(2014,1,1), periods=10, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(new_index)), new_index)
df.index.name = 'DATES'
df.rename(columns={0:'test'}, inplace=True)
df.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's treating `DATES` as an index and offsets the index by one row to match the output you have above. There was a discussion about it on [Github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6260).

There's a note in the docs here with a solution: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/io.html#excel-files

You want to use the `merge_cells=False` kwarg in `to_excel`